# pad the prompt with dots if the length of the prompt is less than n

Tags: zsh, prompt

Thanks to [Klas Mellbourn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370276/206574) my current prompt looks like

```
# this variable can be changed later to change the fraction of the line 
export PROMPT_PERCENT_OF_LINE=40

# make a function, so that it can be evaluated repeatedly
function myPromptWidth() { 
  echo $(( ${COLUMNS:-80} * PROMPT_PERCENT_OF_LINE / 100 )) 
}

# for some reason you can't put a function right in PROMPT, so make an
# intermediary variable
width_part='$(myPromptWidth)'

# if myPromptWidth is less than current prompt ... pad with dots

PS1="%F{013}%${width_part}<...<%d%f%F{012}\${__git_ps1_foo}%f%F{011}%(1j.jobs%j.)%f%(?.%F{004}.%F{001}✕%?)%<<%# %f"
```

So the output is something like

```
/media/blueray/WDPurple/_DataBackup/_Work/_NotesFilteredADOC% cd ~
/home/blueray%
```

But I want all prompts to be of same length. If a prompt length is less than `myPromptWidth` it should be padded with dots.

So my expected output is

```
/media/blueray/WDPurple/_DataBackup/_Work/_NotesFilteredADOC% cd ~
.............................................../home/blueray%
```

How can I achieve that?

**Update 1**

I have been experimenting with `%${width_part}(l.true-text.false-text)`. Not sure if this can be used so solve the problem.

Comment: You could always add `$(myPromptWidth)` worth of dots at the start.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, but I could not find the length of my current prompt. If I could find the length of my current prompt then I could append dots using `$(myPromptWidth)-$CurrentPromptLength`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
width_part='$((${COLUMNS:-80} * PROMPT_PERCENT_OF_LINE / 100))'
PS1="%F{013}%$width_part<<\${(l[$width_part][.])}%~%F{012}\${__git_ps1_foo}%F{011}%(1j.jobs%j.)%(?.%F{004}.%F{001}✕%?)%<<%# %f"
```

That as is, we still do truncation with `%<width><<truncated-part%<<`, though with an empty substitution string (the `...` is gone) but instead insert `<width>` worth of `.` at the beginning of the `truncated-part` with `${(l[<width>][.])}` which is the left-padding parameter expansion flag here applied to no parameter at all.

You'll notice the whole thing is *double*-quoted, and some of the `$`s are escaped and some are not. The ones that are not (`$width_part`) are expanded at the time of that assignment, the ones that are will be inserted literally into `$PS1`, so they will be expanded at the time each prompt is computed. The actual value of that `$PS1` variable is:

```
%F{013}%$((${COLUMNS:-80} * PROMPT_PERCENT_OF_LINE / 100))<<${(l[$((${COLUMNS:-80} * PROMPT_PERCENT_OF_LINE / 100))][.])}%~%F{012}${__git_ps1_foo}%F{011}%(1j.jobs%j.)%(?.%F{004}.%F{001}✕%?)%<<%# %f
```

Comment: Marhaba Marhaba !!!

Comment: I only did not understand `<<\$` in `<<\${(l[$width_part][.])}`

Comment: @blueray, see edit.

Comment: seeing the padding with brackets like this `${(l[$width_part][.])}` makes the other syntax make a lot more sense `${(l:$width_part::.:)}`. I've always wondered about the double `::` in the middle!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would fill the prompt to an appropriate number of dots, using your `myPromptWidth` function:

```
width="$(myPromptWidth)"
print -v dots -f '%*s' $width .
dots=${dots// /.} 
PS1="%$width<...<$dots %/%% "
```

The resulting prompt is like:

```
......................./tmp%
```

`dots` needs to contain a sufficient number of dots, the above is probably just one way to build it.

This is pretty much what Stéphane just commented, while I was writing it: fill the prompt with dots and let the shell truncate it to length.

Note that this will also truncate the actual useful part of the prompt if it's longer than `$width`.

Comment: For some reason, I am not understanding how to use this code. Can you please add this code with the code I have provided in the question.

Comment: @blueray, I didn't look too closely into replicating your prompt, as I find long prompt strings like that really hard to decipher. So I just used `%/%%` as a placeholder. I edited it a bit, but as usual, Stéphane has a more succinct solution. :)

Comment: We normally can not thank people in the comment section for the help they have provided. However, please do know that we appreciate it greatly.